# How to remember the buttons click state and their functions with local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have many buttons that change/add/remove elements. Some of the elements are dynamic e.g. clicking button **one** will create button **two** etc.

I'd like to save the state of the buttons/page in local storage. If I clicked button one, and then two, the background is now red. When the visitor returns (after browser close) it will be as if they have already clicked one>two and will see the red background as before.

I've been reading Mozilla setItem and every post on Stackoverflow about local storage but I can't find any examples of this exact scenario.
https://jsfiddle.net/oh9q2Lzw/1/

```js
$('.one').on('click', function() {
  $('.blue').removeClass('blue').addClass('green');
});

$('.two').on('click', function() {
  $('.green').removeClass('green').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.blue {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: blue
}

.green {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: green
}

.red {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>

<br>
<div class="box">
  <button class="one">one</button>
  <button class="one">one</button>
  <button class="two">two</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="blue"></div>
<br>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

Comment: You could store it in cookies on client side.

Comment: There's no need to find this exact scenario. You need to come up with the simplest data structure capable of storing the entire state. You're adding classes to identical divs, so you simply need to store the list of currently added classes somehow. The simplest way is to get the `.classList` of one div, iterate over it, put all classes into an array and store it (actually its stringifyfied version, because localStorage only supports strings)

Comment: Also note that this problem becomes much easier to solve if you keep the array of classes from the start, and change both it and your divs when a button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the only memory the page needs is the class name of the divs applied when the style was last changed.

Therefore, the simple solution is to store the class name in local storage each time it changes by modifying your button events as follows:

```
    $('.one').on('click', function() {
      $('.blue').removeClass('blue').addClass('green');
      localStorage.setItem("div-class", "green");
    });

    $('.two').on('click', function() {
      $('.green').removeClass('green').addClass('red');
      localStorage.setItem("div-class", "red");
    });
```

When the page loads, the hard-coded class is always "blue" and so this can be changed if a value is stored in local storage.

This is done by adding a function to the `window.onload` event:

```
window.onload = function() {
      if (localStorage.getItem("div-class")) {
            $('.blue').removeClass('blue').addClass(localStorage.getItem("div-class"));
      }
    };
```

The SO snippet tool doesn't allow local storage access but I've modified your JS fiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/g5wqjo2h/

I've also made a modified version with an extra button to allow you to clear localStorage during development. If the `clear memory` button is clicked, when the js Fiddle is next run or loaded, the divs return to the default blue class. Otherwise, the previous colour is loaded from localStorage. : https://jsfiddle.net/g5wqjo2h/1/

Comment: Thanks, my buttons actually do quite a lot more than the example like change/add/remove classes and elements so I could see this getting fairly large with 10+ buttons. Shame local storage can't just see that a button was clicked and run the on-click script.

Comment: You can modify it to store a string holding the function name you want to execute on load, and then access that function as a property of the `window` object when the page loads - `window["storedFunctionName"]()` - will execute the function `storedFunctionName()`. you would have to pass the 'old' class to it as it would not necessarily be replacing "blue" but that is trivial by setting two items - the function to call, and a parameter value such as "blue" for the previous class.

Comment: Actually, because of the sequential way your classes are applied, you only need to store the function name. Replace the function in your click handlers with calls to named functions holding equivalent statements and store/retrieve the function name as described in my last comment.